# Joining two time series using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two time series. Both series have same columns. They have some common dates. One of columns of both series is Close representing closing price. I want to inner join these closing prices. I have used following code. But it is generating error in last line.

```
dow=pd.read_csv("dow.csv",index_col="Date")
sensex=pd.read_csv("sensex.csv",index_col="Date")
dow_close=dow["Close"]
sensex_close=sensex["Close"]
dow_close.index=pd.to_datetime(dow_close.index)
sensex_close.index=pd.to_datetime(sensex_close.index)
dow_sensex_close=dow_close.join(sensex_close,how='inner')
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? Are you getting an error, or is the result different to what you expect? What data is in `dow.csv`? What result do you expect? What result are you getting?

Comment: dow and sensex consists of six columns. I want to join close columns of both series. In above syntax last line is producing error

Comment: The point of my comment above is that you are missing a lot of important information from your question. Update your question with the answers to all the bits I've asked, including actual data from the input files and what the output actually looks like, and what you want it to look like, and someone might be able to suggest an answer

Comment: Did you get the error that `'Series' object has no attribute 'join'`?

Comment: At least tell us what error message did you get.

Comment: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'
I got above error in last line of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is your method of sub-setting. Use .loc function for sub-setting. You will get new data frame as data frame not series. Then use .join function along with ls and rs suffix.

```
dow=pd.read_csv("dow.csv",index_col="Date")
sensex=pd.read_csv("sensex.csv",index_col="Date")
dow_close=dow.loc[:,["Close"]]
sensex_close=sensex.loc[:,["Close"]]
dow_close.index=pd.to_datetime(dow_close.index)
sensex_close.index=pd.to_datetime(sensex_close.index)
dow_sensex_close = dow_close.join(sensex_close,how='inner',lsuffix='_dow', rsuffix='_sensex')
dow_sensex_close.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke *join*, the *other* object can be a *Series*, but the
*self* object must be just a **DataFrame**.

So the first correction is to run:

```
dow_close.to_frame().join(sensex_close, ...)
```

But it is not enough, since you have overlapping columns.
To avoid another exception (*columns overlap but no suffix specified*),
you have to specify at least one of *lsuffix* and *rsuffix*.

My suggestion is to specify both of them:

```
dow_sensex_close = dow_close.to_frame().join(sensex_close,
    how='inner', lsuffix='_dow', rsuffix='_sensex')
```